# I can't give fragment as argument inside ViewModelProviders.of() function

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, viewmodelproviders

I want to define ViewModel in fragment  but the function is not working properly.

I created a ViewModel class as FeedViewModel . And now I want to define it in fragment  but the function is not working properly.I checked out the gradle file but can't find the solution.
of function is wrong

Error Message :None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
of(Fragment) defined in android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
of(FragmentActivity) defined in android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders

```
private lateinit var viewModel : FeedViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FeedViewModel::class.java)
  //  viewModel.refreshData()


}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Kt5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[FeedViewModel::class.java]
```